# TIdHash128 Missing From Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-xe3

I am having a problem with `Delphi XE3's Indy10`. I cannot locate the class `TIdHash128`.

Indy's documentation states this should be found in `IdHash.pas` but this is not the case on my PC. Oddly enough the comment at the top of `IdHash.pas` reads `"Rev 1.10    7/24/04 12:54:32 PM  RLebeau Compiler fix for TIdHash128.HashValue()"` despite having no definition for `TIdHash128` in the file. I have also done a search through the source files but no `TIdHash128` was found.

Is this supposed to be missing from XE3's version of Indy10?

Comment: I can see the class being removed in rev. 1773 by Remy. That revision was commited in nov/2006, so this is not a recent change. Unfortunately the commit comments doesn't mention anything about it. Why do you want to use it after all this time? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: IIRC, TIdHash128 was not actualy being used by anything, so it was dead code and got removed. Also, the checkin comments at the top of each Indy file are VERY old, remnants from an earlier source conrol system that Indy stopped using years ago.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks guys. This is because I am trying to migrate from D2007 to XE3 and the source code we use for XML-RPC uses TIdHash128.

Comment: @Ben which version of INDY you used in Delphi 2007? I found the HashValue of TIdHash128 is abstract (no implementation) in all the revisions checked in svn (first from 2005), so if it worked for you, it have to be a very different version from what I can see.

In D2007 you have the source code of Indy, so you can grab the source from there and put it in a new unit under your control as a last resource.

Comment: BTW, if you want me notified about your comments, use the @jachguate notation. I noted your last comment only because I re-visited this question by accident. You get notified on all comments because you're the author of the question